# Applying VLOOKUP function with IF statement to a range

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I'm trying to write a VBA code that would be the equivalent of this excel function for a definite range of cells.

```
=if(A1="", "", vlookup(A1, K1:M2000, 3, false))
```

I want to apply this for range(A1:A15) and insert the function in range (B1:B15) using VBA.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: Try turning on the Macro Recorder, inserting the formula, and look at the resulting VBA.

Comment: But [Why?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: It's really unclear what you want, but you might just need some absolute references then copy paste: I.E. `if(A1 = "", "", Vlookup(A1, $K$1:$M$2000,3,false))`

Comment: Corrected code formatting and clarified title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you'd want to do this, but you can easily make this function in VBA using the below code. The above function will actually be faster and more efficient in the workbook rather than making the below, but it is possible.

Using the below function should now work in your file for cell B1. Then just copy and paste through B2:B15.

=customVLOOKUP(A1,$K$1:$M$2000,3,FALSE)

Note that the last two arguments are set to 3 and false by default, so =customVLOOKUP(A1,$K$1:$M$2000) will give the same result as above

```
Function customVLOOKUP(lookup As Range, lookupRng As Range, Optional lookupCol As Integer = 3, Optional lookupType As Boolean = False) As Variant

' check to see if lookup value is empty string
' if so return empty string to function and exit
' otherwise, evaluate normal vlookup function
If lookup.Value = "" Then

    customVLOOKUP = ""
    Exit Function

Else

    customVLOOKUP = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup.Value2, lookupRng, lookupCol, lookupType)

End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to put that formula into B1:B15 and have all of the column A references adjust as the formula is filled down, you do not need to loop through the cells. Put the formula into the B1:B15 block of cells and the references to column A will adjust automatically.

```
with activesheet   '<-reference this worksheet properly!
    with .range("B1:B15")
        ' use this one
        .formula = "=if(len(A1), iferror(vlookup(A1, K:M, 3, false), """"), """")"
        ' or this one
        .formulaR1C1 = "=if(len(RC[-1]), iferror(vlookup(A1, C11:C13, 3, false), """"), """")"
    end with
end with
```

Note that each of the pairs of double quotes from the original formula needs to be doubled up as they are quotes within a quoted string. I added an [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) to handle non-matches and changes the check on A1 from "" to the [LEN function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/len-lenb-functions-6a149d3a-ba2e-4394-ad47-2eb083265a56) to ease the double of quotes in the formula.